# Removing #SOReadytohelp contest information from 10m page

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, 10m-questions-milestone

As the contest and 4 weeks draws are ended, isn't it good to remove the tweeting #SOreadytohelp contest information from [10m page](https://stackoverflow.com/10m)?

[image: 10m]

Comment: Do you see any links to this page on SO?

Comment: @Rizier Argument valid, but it's still a live link and it won't take much to update it (just removing the "containerInner shirts" `section`). Still worth keeping the sitemap up to date.

Comment: But... I still haven't won the shirt, so the 4 weeks cannot be over!